General expression for fermionic creation operator subspace
This is perhaps a particular case of the question discussed here.
Given a fermionic Fock space $H$ of dimension $2^N$, that is, with $N$ fermionic modes, let $H_n$ be the subspace of states with $n$ occupied fermions, where $n<N$. Let $\hat{c}^\dagger_i$ be the creation operator for the fermionic mode $i$.
Question: Can all operators $\hat{a}^\dagger$ that map $H_n \rightarrow H_{n+1}$ be written in the form
\begin{align}
\hat{a}^\dagger
&= \sum_{i_1} A_{i_1} \hat{c}^\dagger_{i_1} + \sum_{i_1 i_2 j_1} A_{i_1 i_2 j_1} \hat{c}^\dagger_{i_1} \hat{c}^\dagger_{i_2} \hat{c}_{j_1} + ~ ... ~ + \sum_{i_1...i_{N} j_1 ... j_{N-1}} A_{i_1 i_2 j_1} \hat{c}^\dagger_{i_1} ... \hat{c}^\dagger_{i_N} \hat{c}_{j_1} ... \hat{c}_{j_{N-1}} \text{?}
\end{align}
You may consider some normal ordering assumption on the coefficients $A_{i_1...i_m j_1...j_{m-1}}  \in \mathbb{C}$.
As a bonus question, can we therefore associate such an operator to the quasiparticles of any number conserving fermionic Hamiltonian?
I am looking for a formal proof or a discussion with pointing to a proof in the literature.

It is probably better to choose different notations for the number of fermionic modes and the number of fermions.

Thanks for the tip!

To answer your question, will it be enough to present any operator that maps $H_n\rightarrow H_{n+1}$ in some specific way and no matter how it acts on other subspaces, or does this operator have to satisfy additional conditions, such as mapping any subspace $H_{n'}$ for $n'\neq n$ to zero?

It should map $H_n\rightarrow H_{n+1}$ for all $n$, and then map $H_N\rightarrow 0$

It is true for $N=1$ and $N=2$. I think it may be true in general, but I do not think that either of the two answer presented yet prove it...

@hft, could you elaborate on why you consider the answers below insufficient?

One answer was deleted, one was added, and one was edited. Both currently-existing answers are now helpful, IMO.

Any operator $\hat{a}^\dagger$ that maps $H_n \rightarrow H_{n+1}$ for all $n$, with $H_{N+1} \equiv 0$, is defined by set of matrix elements
$$
B^{(n)}_{i_1,\ldots,i_{n+1};j_1,\ldots,j_n} = \langle 0|\hat{c}_{i_{n+1}}\ldots\hat{c}_{i_1}\ \hat{a}^\dagger\ \hat{c}^\dagger_{j_1}\ldots \hat{c}^\dagger_{j_n}|0\rangle
$$
Set of vectors $\hat{c}^\dagger_{j_1}\ldots \hat{c}^\dagger_{j_n}|0\rangle$ with $n = 0,1,\ldots,N$, $1\leq j_1<j_2<\ldots < j_n\leq N$ is the orthonormal basis in fermionic Fock space. Hence the operator $\hat{a}^\dagger$ can be written as
$$
\hat{a}^\dagger = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<\ldots <i_{n+1}\leq N} \sum_{1\leq j_1<\ldots <j_{n}\leq N}B^{(n)}_{i_1,\ldots,i_{n+1};j_1,\ldots,j_n} \hat{c}^\dagger_{i_1}\ldots \hat{c}^\dagger_{i_{n+1}}|0\rangle\langle 0|\hat{c}_{j_{n}}\ldots\hat{c}_{j_1}\tag{a}
$$
It is known that the operator of projection on fermionic vacuum $\hat{P}_0 \equiv |0\rangle\langle 0|$ can be written in the form
$$
\hat{P}_0 =\ :\!\exp\left(-\sum_{k=1}^N\hat{c}_k^\dagger\hat{c}_k\right)\!:\ = \sum_{l = 0}^N\frac{(-1)^l}{l!}\sum_{k_1,\ldots,k_l=1}^N \hat{c}_{k_1}^\dagger\ldots\hat{c}_{k_l}^\dagger \hat{c}_{k_l}\ldots\hat{c}_{k_1}.\tag{P0}
$$
I believe that this formula should be derived in Berezin's book on the method of second quantization. Or one can check it by using following equalities
$$
\sum_{k_1,\ldots,k_l=1}^N \hat{c}_{k_1}^\dagger\ldots\hat{c}_{k_l}^\dagger \hat{c}_{k_l}\ldots\hat{c}_{k_1} = \hat{n}_f(\hat{n}_f-1)\ldots(\hat{n}_f-l+1) = \frac{\hat{n}_f!}{(\hat{n}_f-l)!},
$$
where $\hat{n}_f = \sum_{k=1}^N\hat{c}_k^\dagger\hat{c}_k$ is the fermion number operator. It is also easy to check the validity of the following equalities
$$
\hat{c}^\dagger_{i_1}\ldots \hat{c}^\dagger_{i_{n+1}}\hat{P}_0 = \hat{c}^\dagger_{i_1}\ldots \hat{c}^\dagger_{i_{n+1}}\sum_{l = 0}^{N-n-1}\frac{(-1)^l}{l!}\sum_{k_1,\ldots,k_l=1}^N \hat{c}_{k_1}^\dagger\ldots\hat{c}_{k_l}^\dagger \hat{c}_{k_l}\ldots\hat{c}_{k_1},\tag{P1}.
$$
Now, substituting (P1) into (a) gives the equality
$$
\hat{a}^\dagger = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\ \sum_{l = 0}^{N-n-1}\frac{(-1)^l}{l!}\sum_{1\leq i_1<\ldots <i_{n+1}\leq N} \sum_{1\leq j_1<\ldots <j_{n}\leq N}\sum_{k_1,\ldots,k_l=1}^N B^{(n)}_{i_1,\ldots,i_{n+1};j_1,\ldots,j_n}
$$
$$
\hat{c}^\dagger_{i_1}\ldots \hat{c}^\dagger_{i_{n+1}}\hat{c}_{k_1}^\dagger\ldots\hat{c}_{k_l}^\dagger \hat{c}_{k_l}\ldots\hat{c}_{k_1}\hat{c}_{j_{n}}\ldots\hat{c}_{j_1}
$$
that has exactly the desired form.

I think it is p.29 in Berezin's book.

Yes, you can. To prove this, let us first define what we mean by a general fermionic creation operator.
Let $f_n: \mathcal{H}_n \to \mathcal{H}_{n+1}$ be a linear map from the Hilbert space of $n$ fermions to $n+1$ fermions. A general fermion creation operator would be defined as
$$
f = f_0 \oplus f_1 \oplus f_2 \oplus \dots \oplus f_{N-1}
$$
for arbitrary choices of $f_n$.
Next, we want to prove that any such $f$ can be expressed in the form you described, that is,
$$
f = \sum_{i_1} A_{i_1} c^\dagger_{i_1} +  \sum_{i_1,i_2,j_1} A_{i_1,i_2,j_1} c^\dagger_{i_1}c^\dagger_{i_2}c_{j_1} + \dots
$$
I will just sketch the proof.

Look a general operator of the form $\sum_{i_1,\dots ,i_{n+1},j_1,\dots, j_n} A_{i_1\dots i_{n+1}j_1\dots j_n} c^\dagger_{i_1}\dots c^\dagger_{i_{n+1}}c_{j_1}\dots c_{j_n} $. Show that for any $f_n$, there is a choice for the matrix $A$ such that the action of that operator on $\mathcal{H}_n$ is the same as $f_n$. You can show this constructively by deriving the required matrix elements of $A$ by looking at the matrix elements of $f_n$. Let us call this operator $g_n$. Note that $g_n \neq f_n$ as it also has nontrivial action on $\mathcal{H}_k, k>n$.

Let $k>n$. The action of $g_n$ on $\mathcal{H}_k$ can be cancelled by adding a counterterm
$$
g_{k,n}(g_n)=-\sum_{i_1,\dots ,i_{n+1},j_1,\dots, j_n} A^{(g_n)}_{i_1\dots i_{n+1}j_1\dots j_n} c^\dagger_{i_1}\dots c^\dagger_{i_{n+1}} \bigg(\sum_{m_1,\dots,m_{k-n}}c^\dagger_{m_1}\dots c^\dagger_{m_{k-n}}c_{m_{k-n}}\dots c_{m_1}\bigg)c_{j_1}\dots c_{j_n}
$$

Define $h_0 = g_0, h_n = g_n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}g_{n,k}(h_k)$.

Show that $f = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h_n$. Each of the $h_n$ are manifestly in the form you require.


This constructively shows that for any $f_n$, there exists a choice of $A_{i_1}, A_{i_1,i_2,j_1},\dots$ such that
$$
f = f_0 \oplus f_1 \oplus f_2 \oplus \dots \oplus f_{N-1} = \sum_{i_1} A_{i_1} c^\dagger_{i_1} +  \sum_{i_1,i_2,j_1} A_{i_1,i_2,j_1} c^\dagger_{i_1}c^\dagger_{i_2}c_{j_1} + \dots.
$$

Explanation of the direct sum notation:
I will give an explicit explanation of the direct sum notation for $N=2$. The Fock space is spanned by
$$
\vert{00}\rangle,\vert{01}\rangle,\vert{10}\rangle,\vert{11}\rangle
$$
Let us choose $f_0(\vert{00}\rangle) = a \vert{01}\rangle + b \vert{10}\rangle$ and $f_1(\vert{01}\rangle) = c\vert{11}\rangle $, $f_1(\vert{10}\rangle) = d\vert{11}\rangle$. The operator $f_0 \oplus f_1: \mathcal{H}_0\oplus \mathcal{H}_1 \to \mathcal{H}_1\oplus \mathcal{H}_2$ can be naturally extended as an operator $f:\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ by giving it zero action on the $\mathcal{H}_2$ sector. In matrix form, we write
$$
f = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0& 0 & 0 \\
a & 0& 0 & 0 \\
b & 0& 0 & 0 \\
0 & c& d & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
in the occupation number basis listed earlier. Thanks to @hft to helping me clear up the sloppy notation.

"A general fermion creation operator would be defined as..." This does not make sense to me. Are your $\oplus$ symbols supposed to be a direct sum? Can you provide a matrix example for the case of $N=2$ (that is, can you provide an example 4x4 matrix that is a direct sum of $f_0$ and $f_1$)?

@hft it is used in this sense https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360058/formal-definition-of-direct-sum-of-operators as the fermion is Fock space is a direct sum of individual particle number sectors. Does that make sense? Now that you mention it, I am not sure if this is standard notation.

I think that notation is fairly standard, but in matrix notation the direct sum usually looks like a block diagonal matrix. However, the creation operators have off-diagonal components... which is what I don't understand and why I was hoping you could provide an explicit example for $N=2$

Okay, one can naturally generalize that notation to have $A:U_1 \to V_1, B: U_2 \to V_2 \implies A \oplus B : U_1 \oplus U_2 \to V_1 \oplus V_2$ as explained in the answer I linked. It is in this sense that I used the direct sum. In any case, I will write down an example in the main answer.

The example is helpful. The part that seems to go beyond the elementary direct sum is the extension to the full space by giving zero action on the completely full states. Of course this is the right way to do it, but it seemed somewhat implicit. So, as another example, the case of $N=3$ would look like $f=\left(\begin{matrix} 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\ a&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\ b&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\ c&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\ 0&d&g&j&0&0&0&0\ 0&e&h&k&0&0&0&0\ 0&f&i&l&0&0&0&0\ 0&0&0&0&m&n&o&0\\end{matrix}\right)$

I haven't checked the proof, but +1 for the effort thus far.

I agree, it was implicit (and sloppy of me:)). Thanks for asking!

Thank you for the answer and detailed discussion @NandagopalManoj ! I'm still pondering over it to understand it more carefully :)
